# Separate mysqli results with foreach rows

Tags: php, mysqli

Ok, so I am currently trying to set up a script that will be ran as a cron job on the 1st of every month.

It's for a property management system that I'm building. Each property has its charges stored in the MySQL database.

What I need is for the script to go through each block and find the individual fees, then create them as individual invoice entries. It's a bit of a long winded way, but a way that works for us.

Updated code:

```
    <?php

    require_once("lib/common.php");

    $sql = "SELECT id,service_charge,utility_charge,ground_rent,insurance,communalcleaning,maintenance FROM blocks GROUP BY id";

    $rs = $conn->query($sql);

    while($r = $rs->fetch_assoc()){

     foreach($r as $key=>$value) {
      $blkid = $r['id'];
      $invid = time();
      $date = date('Y-m-d');
      switch($key) {
        case "service_charge":
            $type = "Service Charge";
            break;
        case "utility_charge":
            $type = "Utility Charge";
            break;
        case "ground_rent":
            $type = "Ground Rent";
            break;
        case "insurance":
            $type = "Insurance";
            break;
        case "communalcleaning":
            $type = "Communal Cleaning";
            break;
        case "maintenance":
            $type = "Maintenance";
            $ins2 = "INSERT INTO incomings (id,block_id,amount,date) VALUES ('','$blkid','$value','$date')";
            $conn->query($ins2);
            break;
    }

    $ins = "INSERT INTO invoices(id,invoice_id,block_id,entry_description,entry_amount,entry_date) VALUES('','$invid','$blkid','$type','$value','$date')";
    $conn->query($ins);
   }
}

?>
```

** EDIT **

Ok, so I've now edited the code to a much more sensible solution. The problem still exists whereby I need to create new `$invid`'s for each "block_id" that is pulled from the `blocks` table.

Currently is produces the same `$invid` for both blocks. It is separating all of the `$key=>$value`'s as expected, just not splitting the invoices.

I hope I've explained this well enough! Any questions, please do ask!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know you can clear that code with using switch/case and not defining the $ins variable.

Comment: you can write switch case and a function for handling insert queries, rather than repeating the code again and again.

Comment: To add to the other comments, if some queries are re-used, you could cache it in a variable - the query - not the result.

Comment: Just edited the code, thanks for the tip guys! Original problem still lies.

Comment: Why not just use the block_id for your invoice_id?

Comment: Because every month there will be new invoices raised, for the same blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `$invid` to `time()`, which is accurate to the second. Computers are much faster than that, so `$invid` will be repeatedly set to the same number in your loop. The usual approach is to use an auto-incrementing column in MySQL, so it will handle inserting incrementing numbers for the `id` column on its own. Here's how to fix your table:

```
ALTER TABLE `invoices` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

After that, adjust your PHP code so it doesn't even try to insert a value for id. Remove the `$invid` variable and remove the id column from the column and value lists in your `INSERT` statements.

Comment: The `$invid` variable is for a unique invoice ID. The way the entries are put on, are as separate rows. The table has an auto increment column, which is ID. For retrieving single entries.

Comment: Why does the table have two IDs?

Comment: It doesn't. It has an id (Which is AI & PK), and an invoice_id (Which ties all the entries to the relevant invoice.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add a view of the table structure to here.

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE invoices` and add the resulting CREATE statement to your question.